How do you make btrace print the names of the methods it (actually) instruments?
I found debugging btrace scripts infuriatingly hard, thus far. It's hard to tell when instrumentation doesn't run why that happens.
(It could be because you've inserted it the wrong place to begin with, which isn't getting called--usually that's easy to double check with a jdb session with a stop in, but jdb does't take in the regexes so that's only doable in trivial instances. Or btrace silently fails to instrument something--seems to happen more often with jars.)
btracer -v prints all sorts of info about attaching to the VM etc., but nothing about what methods it's (actually succeeding at) inserting instrumentation into. So, how do you make btrace print the exact names of the clazz & methods it (actually) instruments?
(Aside: the flags for btracer don't seem to be 'officially' documented somewhere, but [looking at the shell script] -v adds debug=true to the agent options. Also, the .bat launchers for Windows don't uniformly support these flags [unlike the Unix shell variants], although btracer.bat does support them.)
